# No connectionEventDidOccur for GATT over BR/EDR (aka Classic) using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to use the iOS 13 introduced capability in CoreBluetooth to do GATT over BR/EDR.

The accessory I'm using obviously implements GATT over BR/EDR (it even publishes its services using SDP).

According to the session WWDC 2019 [What's New in Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901/) session, we have to use the `registerForConnectionEvents` API on a `CBCentralManager` instance, providing **services UUIDs** (`CBUUID`s) that will be available to use on the BR/EDR accessory.

In the session, they explicitly say:

> Your app will have instantiated a CBCentralManager, passed us a known
> service UID, and in the case of a BR/EDR or classic device, your user
> will go to the Bluetooth settings and search for the device, in this
> case let's say it's a headset running heart rate.
>
> They'll discover the device, find it, and attempt to connect.
>
> Pairing will be triggered, and then afterwards when we're connected,
> we'll run a service discovery of the GATT services.
>
> If we find a service that you want, then you'll get the delegate
> callback.

So when doing a manual connection in the Settings app to the accessory, iOS does a GATT service discovery and if it matches, we receive an associated `connectionEventDidOccur` delegate callback with the event (`peerConnected`) and the associated `CBPeripheral`.

However, this delegate callback never happens.

I'm using the [UsingCoreBluetoothClassic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/using_core_bluetooth_classic) sample from Apple, with custom service `CBUUID`s implemented by my accessory.
I did multiple attempts: providing only one service `CBUUID`, severals `CBUUID`s, none, generic ones, very specific ones... It never fires.

Note that on Android, it seems to work: connection is possible using the MAC address directly, and a service discovery using **SDP** lists the accessory services.

Also note that the event fires when I'm scanning using `scanForPeripherals` and connect to my accessory (because my accessory also does GATT over BLE, but for specific reasons we explicitly want to perform GATT over BR/EDR).

Is there something I have to do on the accessory that I probably missed ?

Comment: Hey Adam, 

Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @AdrianMacarenco Unfortunately no. Never knew if the issue was coming from iOS or our peripheral. We had to use GATT over BLE and also ExternalAccessory framework since we had an MFI chip.